# Open windows explorer with taskbar programmatically in Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-explorer

I'm currently working with a WPF application in Windows 8. This app is set as the OS's shell, so upon start up, the app automatically launches. Though, what I want to do is upon closure of the app, is to re-launch Explorer w/ the task bar.

I've tried using

```
   Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\..\\explorer.exe");
```

Which works great in Windows 7, but when ran under Windows 8, only the explorer window appears (w/out the taskbar).

Is there something special  I need to in Windows 8? Looking for a C# solution.

Comment: you may perhaps need to set the shell back to explorer and then launch it.